fsk signal duration
I have a bandwidth $B$ and a FSK modulation. The duration of an FSK signal is usually $T_s=1/B$. By drawing a parallel with spread spectrum communication, I can take $T_s=SF/B$ with for example $SF=32$ for the duration of an FSK signal. On the other hand, I would have a loss of data rate.
Is it possible to do this increase in $T_s$?

An FSK signal shifts in frequency at instants spaced $T_s$ apart and the (at least) two tones each need to be at spaced at a multiple of $T_S^{-1}$ Hz apart in order to make them orthogonal. The main lobes (of width $2T_S^{-1}$ Hz) can be overlapping making the minimum bandwidth $B$ for binary FSK to be $3T_S^{-1}$ Hz and $(M+1)T_S^{-1}$ Hz for $M$-ary FSK. My personal view is that $B=4T_S^{-1}$ Hz or $B=5T_S^{-1}$ Hz is makes receiver design simpler that what would needed with a rigid insistence on the minimum $B=3T_S^{-1}$ Hz, but ymmv.  In any case, choosing $SF =32$ and $T_S = 32/B$ would be overkill for binary FSK and even $16$-ary FSK, and a tad inadequate for $32$-ary FSK
